# DIV height : 100% - 55+1px?

Tags: html, css, height

Hi I created a simple template for a "Backend"-Solution.
It looks kinda this :

```
<div id="topnavi"></div>
<div id="mainnavi"></div>
<div id="content"></div>

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background-color:#FCFCFC;
}

#topnavi {
  width:100%;
  height:55px;
  background-image:url('randomurl');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}

#mainnavi {
  width:200px;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:#333333;
}

#content {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

So on TOP there is a Navigation bar with logo and stuff which is set on 55px height (+1px margin on the bottom). Now I want the sidenavigation to take 100% of the browsers window (without scrolling) but if I set
    *{height:100%}
    #mainnavi{100%}
I get a scrollbar because of the 55+1px from the topnavi (at least thats what I guess).
I COULD set the #mainnavi stuff first and THEN set the #topnavi to position:absolute and just let it override it - BUT that would be a dirty solution in my eyes ... is there any other useful work-a-round ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#mainnavi{height:calc(100% - 56px);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc` from CSS3, but it will scale up to page height. If you want to scale it up to screen size, you can add `position: absolute`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fywZT/

Answer (score 1):

The calc directive is definitely a solution in case your browser supports it. Anyway, I've found some issues in the past (issues like, for example, Safari 5 does not support it). Have you tried changing the `box-sizing` property? Something like:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box
```

Here I'm leaving you a link for you to have more information about it - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: What happens with safari ? It just ignore the calc and set the height to 100% ?
box-sizing gives me the same result as working without it sadly :(

Comment: It's just that they implemented the calc method on Safari 6+ :) If you have a device with Safari 5 (which includes iOS 5 and its built-in Safari Mobile) the property is just ignored. About the box-sizing giving the same result... now that I think about it, it's just normal. You have margins there and they're never considered as a part of the entity you're describing, so that property won't help you at all. It would be different if you had issues with padding but... to deal with those margins I'm affraid you'll have to trust in the calc method,as suggested above :)